# R: pass a vector of strings to replace all instances within a string

Tags: r, gsub

If I have:

```
mystring<-"I have one cat, two dogs and three rabbits"
numlist<-c("one","two","three")
```

How do I pass `numlist` into something like `gsub` and replace all instances of a match in `mystring` so that I get:

```
"I have ##NUMBER## cat, ##NUMBER## dogs and ##NUMBER## rabbits"
```

I have tried:

```
> lapply(mystring,arg1=numlist,function(x,arg1) gsub(arg1,"##NUMBER##",x))
[[1]]
[1] "I have ##NUMBER## cat, two dogs and three rabbits"

Warning message:
In gsub(arg1, "##NUMBER##", x) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

because gsub is not vectorized. However I thought lapply could take care of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn` if we need to replace with numbers.

```
 library(gsubfn)
 gsubfn("\\w+", as.list(setNames(1:3, numlist)), mystring)
 #[1] "I have 1 cat, 2 dogs and 3 rabbits"
```

EDIT: I thought that we need to replace with numbers that corresponds to the words in 'numlist'.  But,  iff we need to replace with `##NUMBER##` flag, one option is `mgsub`

```
 library(qdap)
 mgsub(numlist, "##NUMBER##", mystring)
 #[1] "I have ##NUMBER## cat, ##NUMBER## dogs and ##NUMBER## rabbits"
```

Comment: I believe that if you run benchmarks that mgsub is the fastest solution this far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply`, *or* you can construct a regular expression from your search strings:

```
gsub(paste(numlist, collapse = '|'), '##NUMBER##', mystring)
```

This will match any of the strings in `numlist`.

When using `lapply`, you need to invert your arguments, since you want to apply the function over `numlist`, not over `mystring`; furthermore, your function must take exactly one argument:

```
lapply(numlist, function (num) gsub(num, '##NUMBER##', mystring))
```

This will, however, yield a different result; namely, it will return *three* result strings, each with a different word replaced:

```
[[1]]
[1] "I have ##NUMBER## cat, two dogs and three rabbits"

[[2]]
[1] "I have one cat, ##NUMBER## dogs and three rabbits"

[[3]]
[1] "I have one cat, two dogs and ##NUMBER## rabbits"
```

Comment: while the replacement is good, I really do have to have only one result returned.

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant way, but it works,

```
x <- "I have ##NUMBER## cat, ##NUMBER## dogs and ##NUMBER## rabbits"
numlist <- c("one","two","three")

for (i in 1:length(numlist)) {
  loc <- regexpr("##NUMBER##", x)
  start_loc <- loc[[1]]
  width <- attr(loc, "match.length")
  x <- paste(substr(x, 1, start_loc - 1), numlist[i], substr(x, start_loc + width, nchar(x)), sep = "")
}
```

Output:

```
> x
[1] "I have one cat, two dogs and three rabbits"
```